# Find piped to awk redirected to new files

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I'm trying to find a group of files

```
> find . -type f -iregex .*geojson$
> ./dir1/london.geojson
  ./manchester.geojson
```

Then for each file found (30 to 40 in many nested folders), I want to add my own json structure around the original, adding in the filename and an extracted id. Just like so:

```
> cat manchester.geojson
  {"properties": { "id": 11.0, "borough": "Didsbury" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }
  {"properties": { "id": 22.0, "borough": "Chorlton" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }
```

I would like the following result:

```
{"_id": 11.0, filename": "manchester.geojson", "document": {"properties": { "id": 11.0, "borough": "Didsbury" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }}
{"_id": 22.0, filename": "manchester.geojson", "document": {"properties": { "id": 22.0, "borough": "Chorlton" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }}
```

The closest I've got is piping to xargs and awk like this:

```
> find . -type f -iregex .*geojson$ | xargs -d '\n' awk -F'[{:,]' '{print "{ \"_id\":"$7", \"file\": \""FILENAME"\", \"doc\": " $0 " }"}'

  }"_id": 11.0, "file": "./manchester.geojson", "doc": { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 11.0, "borough": "Didsbury" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }}
  }"_id": 22.0, "file": "./manchester.geojson", "doc": { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 22.0, "borough": "Chorlton" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }}
```

I don't know what exactly is wrong with the opening curly brace?

I can get to all the variables I would like to, see this example:

```
> find . -type f -iregex .*geojson$ | xargs -d '\n' awk -F'[{:,]' '{print  $7 " " FILENAME " " $0}'

  11.0 ./manchester.geojson { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 11.0, "borough": "Didsbury" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }}
  22.0 ./manchester.geojson { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 22.0, "borough": "Chorlton" }, "geometry": {"removed": 0} }}
```

Then finally there is the question of sending each files output to a new file with the same name but with a new extension. I can send the whole output of the many files into one big file with a simple > redirect but that is not what I need. Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Comment: Your input files contain a trailing control-M at the end of each line which is sending the cursor back to the start of the line before printing the explicit `}` you're adding. Run `cat -v` to see it and `dos2unix` or similar to remove it.

Comment: Thanks Ed, first issue solved, now i just need to be able to redirect out to a new file

Comment: Change `print foo` to `print foo > "new_file"`.

Comment: Its not just as easy as redirecting to a file like that as that causes all the output from all the files to go to the same static file. In the end I've used the inplace flag on the awk command.

Comment: Yes it is and no it doesn't if you don't want it to, just create different output file names as you go, e.g. `some condition{ close(out); out="new_file" ++cnt} ... {print > out}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to both @EdMorton and @glenjackman for helping to point me in the right direction. In the end i was almost there with the question. Once the dodgy line endings were cleaned up the following single line does the job:

```
> find . -type f -name \*geojson | xargs -d '\n' awk -i inplace -F'[:,]' '{print "{ \"_id\":" $5 ", \"file\": \"" FILENAME "\", \"doc\": "$0"}"}'
```

The missing piece was the `-i inplace` to modify the file in place which was an option i had not initially considered.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON parser to work with JSON data. [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a good one.

```
jqbody='{_id: .properties.id, filename: input_filename, document: .}'
find . -type f -name \*geojson -print0 | while read -rd "" filename; do
    jq  -c "$jqbody" "$filename" ## > ./tmpfile && mv ./tmpfile "$filename"
done
```

If things look OK, remove the `##` comment.

I can't see an equivalent of "edit inplace" option for jq, so I need to use a shell while loop to get the filename, instead of xargs.

---

The output:

```
{"_id":11,"filename":"./manchester.geojson","document":{"properties":{"id":11,"borough":"Didsbury"},"geometry":{"removed":0}}}
{"_id":12,"filename":"./manchester.geojson","document":{"properties":{"id":12,"borough":"Chorlton"},"geometry":{"removed":0}}}
```

I see that the id numbers got "integerized". To avoid that, your original JSON should quote the id value so it gets handled verbatim as a string.

Comment: Really good, thanks. The only one issue is that the id needs to come from the record itself i used 1.0 and 2.0 but it could also be 98765 and 1234.567 its a number but not sequential. Unfortunately the example i used in the question was misleading.  I will update my examples to be clear.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @glennjackman. I wanted to try and keep this to one statement on one line, also the docker container that this runs in does not have jq. Clearly this could be added but would be an extra dependency that i was hoping not to have to install.